# How to get file name from a specified folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the file name resides under a specified folder.

i.e. there is a file stored under two folders `First\Second\test.txt` I want have the path of the parent directory of file that is `First\Second\` in my program. Now I want to get the file name residing under the directory "Second" using code.

Please help me.

Comment: What do you exactly need? do you want to get all the files from `second` folder, or do you want to get the filename from path, your question is not really clear

Comment: There only single file resides in second folder. That file name I want to get. @Habib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do the trick if you want one file.

```
using System.IO; 
using System.Linq

var file = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\First\\Second\\").FirstOrDefault();

if (file != null)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
}
```

The following will get you all the file names:

```
using System.IO; 
using System.Linq

var files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\First\\Second\\");
var fileNames = files.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) method to get the files in directory with complete path and later use these files path to extract files names.

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
```

To get the files names without path you can use linq

```
var fileNames System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory).Select(c => Path.GetFileName(c)).ToList();
```

Comment: This will get the full file paths. Not the file names. My answer below will get just the names. You need the Path.GetFileName call.

Comment: I did not look at your answer dear, just realized from your comment that my answer is not getting files names.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

1)

```
string sourceDir = @"C:\First\Second\";
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);

foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
{
   // do something with fileName
   Console.WriteLine(fileName);
}
```

2)

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Location);
foreach (System.IO.FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(f.Name); 
}
```